Spring Integration Jaxb Unmarshaller mapping Schema variable names instead of @XMLElement values
I have this JAXB-XJC Generated SCHEMA,
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "Response", propOrder = {
    "value",
    "account",
    "hash",
    "tstamp",
    "msg",
    "code",
    "authCode",
    "startBal",
    "endBal"
})
public class Response {

    protected Amount value;
    @XmlElement(required = true)
    protected Account account;
    protected String hash;
    protected TimeStamp tstamp;
    protected String msg;
    @XmlElement(required = true)
    protected String code;
    @XmlElement(name = "auth_code")
    protected String authCode;
    @XmlElement(name = "start_bal")
    protected Amount startBal;
    @XmlElement(name = "end_bal")
    protected Amount endBal;

And my Spring integration uses this unmarshaller
<oxm:jaxb2-marshaller id="abcMarshaller" context-path="com.abc.schema"/>


My Problem is during unmarshalling the XML Elements are mapped using variable name and >not @XMLElement. So 'account' works but 'end_bal' doesn't ( because its looking for >variable named end_bal, but found endBal).

I am on JAVA 17 , Spring 4 and likely on jakarta.xml.bind-api 4.0.2 API.

Please suggest how to fix this primarily within spring integration xml.

Spring 4 doesn't support Jakarta XML but you need to use Java XML (the older API). So make sure you have the right version.

This has nothing to do with Spring Integration, but rather with JAXB itself.
Nevertheless it still works for me:
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType
@XmlRootElement(name = "person")
public class JaxbAnnotatedPerson {

    @XmlElement(name = "firstname")
    private String firstName;

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

}

and unit test against an XML config like this:
<si-xml:unmarshalling-transformer id="unmarshaller" input-channel="unmarshallIn" output-channel="unmarshallOut" unmarshaller="marshallerUnmarshaller" />

<oxm:jaxb2-marshaller id="marshallerUnmarshaller">
    <oxm:class-to-be-bound name="org.springframework.integration.xml.transformer.jaxbmarshaling.JaxbAnnotatedPerson"/>
</oxm:jaxb2-marshaller>>

(With a context-path it fails for me like this:
Caused by: jakarta.xml.bind.JAXBException: "org.springframework.integration.xml.transformer.jaxbmarshaling" doesnt contain ObjectFactory.class or jaxb.index

But I guess that has nothing to do with your problem.)
And junit test is:
@Test
public void testUnmarshalling() {
    StringSource source = new StringSource("<person><firstname>bob</firstname></person>");
    this.unmarshallIn.send(new GenericMessage<Source>(source));
    Message<?> res = this.unmarshallOut.receive(2000);
    assertThat(res).as("No response").isNotNull();
    assertThat(res.getPayload() instanceof JaxbAnnotatedPerson).as("Not a Person ").isTrue();
    JaxbAnnotatedPerson person = (JaxbAnnotatedPerson) res.getPayload();
    assertThat(person.getFirstName()).as("Wrong firstname").isEqualTo("bob");
}

Please, share with us a stack trace for an error you are observing.
